# Get loaded database_clenaer gem version

Tags: ruby, database-cleaner

[DatabaseCleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) doesn't expose a way to inquiry the version. The [version is done via YAML file](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/blob/fe1d9f840005b910e9f7ede90483280beb3f8408/database_cleaner.gemspec#L2). How could I know the loaded gem version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [load the specification from RubyGems](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/d9bbed7d35fe6fbcd955cf299f56bd8953ec96d1/lib/rubygems.rb#L1229):

```
Gem.loaded_specs["database_cleaner"].version.to_s
```